# Form being resubmitted when fancybox is close

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, fancybox

I have three different forms in the fancybox, when i click the button for any of the forms, all three forms will be submitted and the fancybox will be closed.
But the form is being resubmitted when fancybox closes.

Javascript for buttons.

```
function submitForms() {
            groupRoleMapping();
            parent.jQuery.fn.fancybox.close();
            return false;
}
function groupUserMapping() {
           //loop to find checked checkbox
          en_Method_PostWithURL(formAction, {id: ${group.id}, rowId: array3, update: "group"});

}
function groupUpate() {
            var formAction = $("#updateGroup").attr("action");
            en_Method_PostWithURL(formAction, {id: ${group.id}, update: "group", status: "yes", groupName: document.getElementById('groupName').value, description: document.getElementById('description').value});

}
function groupRoleMapping() {
           groupUpate();
           groupUserMapping();
          en_Method_PostWithURL(formAction, {id: ${group.id}, rowId: array3, update: "groupToRole"});
}
```

Form in jsp

```
 <form method="POST"  action="${contextPath}/updateGroup.htm" id="updateGroup" >
                <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" class="form-control" type="text" value="${group.id}" required/>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="userName">Group:</label>
                    <input id="groupName" name="groupName" class="form-control" type="text" value="${group.group}" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="userName">Description:</label>
                    <input id="description" name="description" class="form-control" type="text" value="${group.description}" required/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id ="sendUpdate" onclick="return submitForms();" class="btn btn-default"  >Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <form id="groupUserMapping" method="POST"  action="${contextPath}/updateUserToGroup.htm">
                <table id="examplee" class="hover" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>


                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="submit" id ="sendUpdate" onclick="return submitForms()" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <form id="groupRoleMapping" method="POST"  action="${contextPath}/updateRoleToGroup.htm">
                <table id="examples" class="hover" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>


                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return submitForms()" >Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: can you share Fiddle of the same ?

Comment: not able to show Fiddle, as the fancybox is shown after clicking on a dynamic link

Comment: You have the option to keep static link for demonstration..